# Game about a car which has to cover 100km distance

Tags: javascript

This is my assignment:

> There is a car with 30L of petrol.
>
> It needs to travel from 0 to 100 KMs.
>
> The car moves in steps, at each step car can move between 0 KM to 6 KM
> (generate a random number).
>
> The car has a mileage of 1 KM/L.
>
> You can place 5 random petrol pumps on the road.
>
> Every time the car reaches the petrol pump exactly, the car gets a
> refill of 20 L.
>
> Write a JavaScript code to run this game and print every step of the
> car with the current position, petrol remaining.
>
> Add a button on the page "Start" which should start the game. Print
> the result of the game in the document window.
>
> If the start button is clicked again, it should clear the window and
> start the game again.

I want to check whether the car has passed a petrol pump or not if yes then add 20l , if not continue, but the code doesnt break out of the switch statement. My code below:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const btn = document.getElementById('butt');
    btn.addEventListener('click', startTheGame);
    const rootbody = document.querySelector('.rootbody');
    const start = document.querySelector('.start');

    function startTheGame() {
        if (rootbody.innerHTML === '') {
            const header = document.createTextNode('Game Started!');
            start.appendChild(header);
            const p = {
                PP1: 15,
                PP2: 30,
                PP3: 45,
                PP4: 60,
                PP5: 75,
            };

            const pps = document.createTextNode(
                `Petrol Pumps generated at ${p.PP1}, ${p.PP2}, ${p.PP3}, ${p.PP4}, ${p.PP5} `
            );
            rootbody.appendChild(pps);

            let posi = 0;
            let rem = 30;
            while (posi < 100) {
                // Generate a random number
                const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
                // For every random number you generate, add it to posi to get the position
                // till that point
                posi = posi + random;
                rem = parseInt(rem - random);
                switch (posi) {
                    case 15:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    case 16:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    case 17:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    case 18:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    case 19:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    case 20:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                switch (posi) {
                    case 30:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    case 31:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    case 32:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    case 33:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    case 34:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    case 35:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                switch (posi.value) {
                    case 45:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    case 46:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    case 47:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    case 48:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    case 49:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    case 50:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                switch (posi) {
                    case 60:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    case 61:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    case 62:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    case 63:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    case 64:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    case 65:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    case 66:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                switch (posi) {
                    case 75:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    case 76:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    case 77:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    case 78:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    case 79:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    case 80:
                        rem += 20;
                        console.log(`petrol rem ${rem}`);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                // check whether you have reached the destination or not
                // if reached break out of the loop and display destination
                // reached!!!!

                if (posi >= 100) {
                    document.body.querySelector(
                        '.rootbody'
                    ).innerHTML += ` - ${random}Kms travelled, Destination reached`;
                    break;
                }

                // append the posi and the step

                document.body.querySelector(
                    '.rootbody'
                ).innerHTML += `<br />Step - ${random}Kms travelled, position ${posi},
                petrol remaining ${rem}L
                <br/>`;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty certain it *does* break out of the respective `switch` statement, isn't your problem rather that it then enters the *next* `switch` statement?

Comment: You'll be annoyed when you'll have to replace `rem += 20` by `rem += 25`. [DRY !](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: Do not use a `switch` statement to check whether you passed a petrol station. Use a list of positions at which the stations are placed, then check for each whether the old position (`posi`) was before the station and the new position (`posi + random`) is beyond it. If yes, you passed it, fill up.

Comment: sometimes you switch over `posi` and sometimes over `posi.value`, and why you have so many cases which are THE SAME? this is a mess.

Comment: @Bergi yes it does break out of the switch but when the while loops iterates the next value ,  the compiler runs throught the same code again which i dont want. My aim is, once one out of the 6 conditions of the switch cases is met break the whole switch statement because i dont need it in future.

Comment: @bergi would you please edit so i would know where i am doing wrong?

Comment: @BhatShakran Ah, I see. No, you can't do that. You'd need six boolean variables that you check off once you hit a station, and then wrap each `switch` statement in an `if` with the respective condition… But as I said, this is the wrong way to go anyway.

Comment: @bergi how do i check whether the car has passed the station or not?

Comment: @BhatShakran Like I wrote, "*check for each [station] whether the old position (`posi`) was before the station and the new position (`posi + random`) is beyond it.*" You can make it more explicit by doing `while (posi < 100) { const oldPosition = posi; const newPosition = posi + random; …; posi = newPosition; }`

Comment: Note that you cannot refill when you are past the station, because _"Every time the car reaches the petrol pump **exactly**, the car gets a refill of 20 L."_ and you cannot _aim_ for it either because _"at each step car can move between 0 KM to 6 KM (generate a **random** number)."_

Answer (score 0):

`switch` statements are good when you have a set of fixed values which you want to test against and want to execute different things based on them. In this case, the pumps are at random locations, and if you later want to go for 500km instead of 100, your code will grow and be unmaintainable.

A better way is to generate an Array of positions like `[10, 20, 25...]` for pump locations, and every time you make a step, check if:

```
// Since we can only refill if there is a pump at the exact location we're at
pumpLocations.includes(position)
```

Then, there are a lot of repetitions in your code. Always think ***DRY*** *(Don't Repeat Yourself)*. If you find yourself rewriting the same code with small changes, try to think of a way to write it once and reuse it (create small reusable functions, for example).

This is also true for constants. If the instructions tell you that refills should be `20` liters, always think to yourself *"How can I make it fast and easy to edit my code in 2 days if this value were to change?"*. This means that you should not put the number `20` everywhere in your code. Store it in a variable once, and reuse it. Also don't write `PP1`, `PP2`, ... `PP5`. Use an Array, and assume that the count can change in the future.

Below is one of the thousand ways to do it.

> **Don't copy and paste!** It looks like your teacher/instructor provided you with a code template, which this example does not follow. So they will know if you did, and you won't learn anything. Instead, try to see the patterns used, and get some inspiration before adapting your version of the exercise.

```js
const rootBody = document.querySelector('.rootbody'),
      btn      = document.getElementById('butt');
      
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  rootBody.innerHTML = '';
  runGame();
});

function runGame() {
  // These values are constant during the game,
  // declare them here once and for all
  const consumptionPerKm    = 1,
        minStep             = 0,
        maxStep             = 6,
        initialPetrol       = 30,
        pumpsCount          = 5,
        refillAmount        = 20,
        startLocation       = 0,
        endLocation         = 100,
        petrolPumpLocations = getRandomIntegers(
                                 pumpsCount,
                                 startLocation,
                                 endLocation
                              ).sort();
                              
  // These represent the state at any given time
  let position = startLocation,
      petrol = initialPetrol;
      
  logStr(`You will find petrol pumps at these positions:\n${
         petrolPumpLocations}\nGood luck!\n`);
         
  if (isAtPump()) {
    petrol += refillAmount; // If there's a pump at the start
  }
      
  logState();
      
  // While we've not reached our destination and still have petrol
  while(position < endLocation && petrol > 0) {
    // Calculate some metrics for this step
    const autonomy          = petrol / consumptionPerKm,
          remainingDistance = endLocation - position,
          maxDistance       = Math.min(autonomy, remainingDistance, maxStep),
          stepDistance      = getRandomInteger(minStep, maxDistance),
          stepConsumption   = stepDistance * consumptionPerKm;
    
    // Adjust the state accordingly
    position += stepDistance;
    petrol -= stepConsumption;

    if (isAtPump()) {
      petrol += refillAmount;
    }
    logState();
  }
  
  if (position === endLocation) {
    logStr("You've reached your destination!");
  } else {
    logStr("Out of petrol :'(");
  }
  
  function isAtPump() {
    return petrolPumpLocations.includes(position);
  }
  
  function logState() {
    let str = `Position: ${position}km\tPetrol: ${petrol}L`;
    if (isAtPump()) {
      str += ` Found a pump! Refilled ${refillAmount}L`;
    }
    logStr(str);
  }
}

function getRandomInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

function getRandomIntegers(n, min, max) {
  const res = [];
  
  while (res.length !== n) {
    const value = getRandomInteger(min, max);
    if (!res.includes(value)) {
      res.push(value);
    }
  }
  
  return res;
}

function logStr(str) {
  rootBody.innerHTML += '\n' + str;
}
```

```html
<button id="butt">Start the game</button>
<pre class="rootbody"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const rootBody = document.querySelector('.rootbody'),
      btn      = document.getElementById('butt');
      
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  rootBody.innerHTML = '';
  runGame();
});

function runGame() {
  // These values are constant during the game,
  // declare them here once and for all
  const consumptionPerKm    = 1,
        minStep             = 0,
        maxStep             = 6,
        initialPetrol       = 30,
        pumpsCount          = 5,
        refillAmount        = 20,
        startLocation       = 0,
        endLocation         = 100,
        petrolPumpLocations = getRandomIntegers(
                                 pumpsCount,
                                 startLocation,
                                 endLocation
                              ).sort();
                              
  // These represent the state at any given time
  let position = startLocation,
      petrol = initialPetrol;
      
  logStr(`You will find petrol pumps at these positions:\n${
         petrolPumpLocations}\nGood luck!\n`);
         
  if (isAtPump()) {
    petrol += refillAmount; // If there's a pump at the start
  }
      
  logState();
      
  // While we've not reached our destination and still have petrol
  while(position < endLocation && petrol > 0) {
    // Calculate some metrics for this step
    const autonomy          = petrol / consumptionPerKm,
          remainingDistance = endLocation - position,
          maxDistance       = Math.min(autonomy, remainingDistance, maxStep),
          stepDistance      = getRandomInteger(minStep, maxDistance),
          stepConsumption   = stepDistance * consumptionPerKm;
    
    // Adjust the state accordingly
    position += stepDistance;
    petrol -= stepConsumption;

    if (isAtPump()) {
      petrol += refillAmount;
    }
    logState();
  }
  
  if (position === endLocation) {
    logStr("You've reached your destination!");
  } else {
    logStr("Out of petrol :'(");
  }
  
  function isAtPump() {
    return petrolPumpLocations.includes(position);
  }
  
  function logState() {
    let str = `Position: ${position}km\tPetrol: ${petrol}L`;
    if (isAtPump()) {
      str += ` Found a pump! Refilled ${refillAmount}L`;
    }
    logStr(str);
  }
}

function getRandomInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

function getRandomIntegers(n, min, max) {
  const res = [];
  
  while (res.length !== n) {
    const value = getRandomInteger(min, max);
    if (!res.includes(value)) {
      res.push(value);
    }
  }
  
  return res;
}

function logStr(str) {
  rootBody.innerHTML += '\n' + str;
}
```

```html
<button id="butt">Start the game</button>
<pre class="rootbody"></pre>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.